# how to access objective-c methods from c++ callback

Tags: c++, objective-c, callback

I want to use a c++ library in an objective-c objective. The c++ library informs my objective-c object about certain value changes of library objects. Therefore I pass a c++ callback function to the library. The callback function looks like this:

```
void positionChanged(int position)
```

Unfortunately there is no **void* data** argument in the callback that I could use to pass a pointer to my objective-c object. Normally I could use such a pointer to get access to my object variables and methods from the c++ callback function whenever the callback is be called. (And I can't change the callback function concerning that).

How can I make a connection between the c++ callback function and my objective-c object to have access to my objective-c object from the c++ callback?

Comment: And you tell the library the function to call (using a function pointer), or it's hardcoded to link to that (global) function?

Comment: I have to register my callback function like "set_callback(positionChanged);"

Comment: So presumably there is only one callback that you can set at once?

Comment: Yes, I just set one callback in my "one and only" objective-c object.

Comment: Can your callback be a C++ class member function, or does it have to be a stand-alone?

Comment: I guess the callback can be a C++ class member function (by the way: can a caller of a callback function recognize if he is calling a static function or an object function? I thought the caller just gets a pointer to a function he calls)

Comment: The syntax is different for member function pointers and free functions. Static members fall into the "free function" category. For the callback to support calling member functions, the callbacks would have to explicitly accept member function pointers to a certain type of object, or use some kind of functor object that abstracts that detail.

Comment: If you only have one Objective-C object, use a "singleton" of some sort to address the object, and reference the singleton in your callback method.  If you have more than one object you'll have to implement some sort of registry -- the details depending on your usage patterns.